# iOS Creating TableViewCell in Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITableViewCell in code using autolayout. But I keep getting this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. DXCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.
```

This is my current code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {
     _image = [UIImageView new];
     _image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     _image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

     [self addSubview:self.clubImage];
     self.shouldUpdate = YES;
     [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) updateConstraints {
  if (self.shouldUpdate) {
    NSDictionary * views = @{@"club" : self.clubImage};
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-6-[club(48)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-6-[club(48)]-6-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
     self.shouldUpdate = NO;
  }

  [super updateConstraints];
}
```

As you can see I'm not overriding layoutSubviews? So I do not understand the error.

The cell is registered through the class and is called in the datasource method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

---

Answer: I am adding the view directly instead of using contentView. This caused the problem and is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

> **DXCell's** implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.

So, check the method `layoutSubviews` under DXCell.m (your custom cell), and call

```
[super layoutSubviews];
```

at the beginning of the override.

Comment: actually the first line in the method should be the super call, not the end

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough but I am not using layoutSubiews in DXCell

Comment: @MouNtant Could you provide all the implementation's code of DXCell?

Comment: @Bigood the implementation is in the question. The init method and updateConstraints

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; with the following

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
[self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Not working and a UItableViewCell class doesn't have a self.view

Comment: @MouNtant sorry about the self.view. Should be self only